# Multiple Windows sessions on one PC using TeamViewer

Tags: windows, teamviewer

Is it possible to connect remotely from PC-A to another PC (let's say PC-B) using TeamViewer and work on that PC-B, without interrupting a local user that is already working with PC-B?

For example, I want to use Microsoft Word and the local user want to work with PowerPoint at the same time. Is that possible?

Comment: To confirm, PC-B is connected TO another user, so viewing their screen, or  PC-B is connected BY another user, so they are viewing PC-B's screen?

Comment: When you connect to the other computer, either the local user gets a prompt asking if it's OK, or the connection goes through because you've set it up that way. In any case a small widget window will appear on the other screen, the other user will be aware of your connection.

Comment: I know the local user will be aware, but I want to know, is that possible to have a remote session with not a disturbing local user, for example, I want to use Microsoft Word and the local user  want to work with PowerPoint at the same time. Is that possible?

Comment: This question belongs on http://superuser.com/ ...

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible.** You can remote control the PC-B from PC-A, but this just means that the user in front of PC-A and the user in front of PC-B both see the desktop of PC-B and both can control the same (Windows) session on PC-B (with appropriate TeamViewer settings).

The only way to achieve what you want is to use Windows Terminal Server support and connect to a different Windows Terminal Server session on PC-B with PC-A. See [TeamViewer FAQ here](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/330-How-does-the-terminal-server-support-work).